# How do I get array to show up in an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, list, function, unordered

I have the following code, and I want the `gather_form_elements` array to show up as an unordered list.
Here is my `html` part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta author="Justin Roohparvar">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\css.css">
<script src="Javascript/form.js"></script>
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="week_1_contact_form.html">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
    <input id="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50" size ="25" placeholder="First Name" required> <br /><br />
    <input id="last_name" type="text" maxlength="50" size="25" placeholder="Last Name" required> <br /><br />
    <input id = "email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> <br /> <br />
    <input id="phone_number" type="tel" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" required><br /><br />
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="getFormElements()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my `form.js` code is below:

```
function getFormElements() {
    var gather_form_elements = new Array(document.getElementById("first_name"), document.getElementById("last_name"), 
    document.getElementById("email"), document.getElementById("phone_number"));

    displayValues(gather_form_elements);
}

function displayValues(gather_form_elements) {
    for(i=0; i<gather_form_elements.length; i++)
    {
        document.write(gather_form_elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The *getFormElements* listener should be on the form's submit handler since forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button. Also, don't name controls after properties of the form (like "submit"), even if the capitalisation is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to get `values` from your inputs, not just elements itself. With your approach, it should look like this:

```
function getFormElements() {
    var gather_form_elements = new Array(document.getElementById("first_name").value, document.getElementById("last_name").value, 
    document.getElementById("email").value, document.getElementById("phone_number").value);

    displayValues(gather_form_elements);
}

function displayValues(gather_form_elements) {
    document.write('<ul>');
    for(i=0; i<gather_form_elements.length; i++)
    {
        document.write('<li>'+gather_form_elements[i]+'</li>');
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks newbie.  I totally forgot about the value function.  I appreciate your help.  This worked just like I wanted it to!

Comment: @JustinRoohparvar Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

As Newbie says, you need to get the value of each controls. A much simpler version of the listener is to make use of the form's *elements* collection. Controls must have a name to be successful, you can leverage that to work out which controls to get the values of:

```js
function getFormElements(form) {
  var values = [];
  [].forEach.call(form.elements, function(control) {
    if (control.name) {
      values.push(control.value);
    }
  });
  // Show values for testing
  console.log(values);
  return values;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="getFormElements(this); return false"> <!-- prevent submit for testing -->
  <h1>Contact Form</h1>
  <input name="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50" size="25" placeholder="First Name" required> <br><br>
  <input name="last_name" type="text" maxlength="50" size="25" placeholder="Last Name" required> <br><br>
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required> <br> <br>
  <input name="phone_number" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This lets you add more controls and doesn't care what you call them.

So only name controls that need a name, don't use IDs if you don't need them and put the submit listener on the form's submit handler so that no matter how the form is submitted, the listener is called. ;-)